# Como configurar hora no bootstrap timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Olá, como faço para configura o timepicker para hora atual ou 01:00?

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
        showInputs: false,
        defaultTime: '',
        minuteStep: 1,
        disableFocus: true,
        template: 'dropdown',
        showMeridian: false

    });
```

Comment: Vc quer uma hora dinâmica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por padrão, a opção `defaultTime` tem seu valor como `current` que é a hora atual, basta remover a opção `defaultTime: ''` que o campo será preenchido automaticamente.

Caso queira definir um horário padrão, basta informar o mesmo:

```
defaultTime: '01:00 AM',
```

#### Referência

- [Bootstrap Timepicker](https://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/)